# Javascript convert date format from "dd/mm/yy" to "mm/dd/yyyy"

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

How could I convert the date format in the input "date1" from "dd/mm/yy" to the input "date2" in the format "mm/dd/yyyy" with Javascript or jQuery:

```
<input id="date1" type="text" value="25/12/21" >
<input id="date2" type="text" value="12/25/2021" >
```

I tried to do this but it doesn't work:

```
var today = new Date($('#date1').val());
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; 
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if(dd<10) 
{
    dd='0'+dd;
} 

if(mm<10) 
{
    mm='0'+mm;
} 
var converted = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;
$('#date2').val(converted);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the value by a `/` to get the month, date and year.

```js
var s = $('#date1').val().split('/')
$('#date2').val(`${s[1]}/${s[0]}/20${s[2]}`)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="date1" type="text" value="25/12/21" >
<input id="date2" type="text" value="12/25/2021" >
```

Comment: Thank you Spectrit! I'd need this as result : "mm/yy/yyyy" (12/25/2021)

Comment: @tonydeleon I've updated my answer. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

you need to swap between mm and dd. like that:

```
var converted = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;
```

Comment: How would you convert it to the result that OP wanted. It would be better to add that code also...

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`array destructing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get the desired result

```js
const [dd, mm, yy] = document.querySelector("#date1").value.split('/');
document.querySelector("#date2").value = `${mm}/${dd}/20${yy}`
```

```html
<input id="date1" type="text" value="25/12/21">
<input id="date2" type="text" value="12/25/2021">
```